# How to send unsent logs to python logging server when it comes back online?

Tags: python, logging, python-3.4

I have successfully created a central python logging server on one computer and can log to it from multiple RPis. However when the logging server goes down the logs are lost. Is there a way to store the logs (in a persistent form) until the logging server becomes available again?

I have looked at a few programs such as graylog, sentry and logstash but couldn't see any option to do this.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you add your code? _How_ do you log to the logging server, what does the server look like?

Comment: [zeromq](http://zguide.zeromq.org/)'s sockets will automagically reconnect and transmit unsent messages when your sever is back online. However the messages will be kept in memory... so not sure if that is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Finwood The code I have atm is the [logging example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network) from the docs. However I am very happy to completely ditch what I already have for a solution to my question.

Comment: @swenzel Thanks, I will take a look at zeromq. But yes ideally I would like something that would store the logs in file(s)/database until successfully sent so that unsent logs persists over an unexpected shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a custom socket handler, which buffers unsent records until delivered. This buffer is being stored in a binary file, therefore the unsent logs are being kept during program restart or system shutdown.

```
import os, os.path
import logging.handlers
import pickle

class BufferingSocketHandler(logging.handlers.SocketHandler):
    def __init__(self, host, port, buffer_file):
        super().__init__(host, port)
        self._buffer = FileBuffer(buffer_file)

    @property  # getter only
    def buffer(self):
        return self._buffer

    def _emit(self, record):
        try:
            s = self.makePickle(record)
            self.send(s)
            return (self.sock is not None)
        except Exception:
            self.handleError(record)
            return False

    def emit(self, record):
        self.send_buffer()
        success = self._emit(record)
        if not success:
            self.buffer.append(record)

    def send_buffer(self):
        try:
            self.acquire()
            success = True
            for item in self.buffer:
                success &= self._emit(item)
            if success:
                self.buffer.flush()
        finally:
            self.release()


class FileBuffer:
    def __init__(self, fname):
        self.fname = fname

    @property
    def size(self):
        return int(os.path.isfile(self.fname) \
                and os.path.getsize(self.fname))

    def append(self, data):
        with open(self.fname, 'ba') as f:
            pickle.dump(data, f)

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            try:
                with open(self.fname, 'br') as f:
                    while True:
                        yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                return

    def flush(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            os.remove(self.fname)
```

When creating a `BufferingSocketHandler` you will have to add a buffer file name, where undelivered log records are being saved until delivery. Data is being serialized using [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html), see the `FileBuffer` class in the example above for details. However, this is a very bare implementation, for more thread safety you might want to add a database for storing log records.

The handler is based on the `logging` module's [`SocketHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/logging.handlers.html#sockethandler), it's [source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/logging/handlers.py#l473) could be interesting as well for understanding the logic behind this modification.

Using [the logging Cookbook's example](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging-cookbook.html#sending-and-receiving-logging-events-across-a-network), the only changes necessary would be importing this custom handler and adding it to the root logger:

```
import logging, logging.handlers
from custom_handlers import BufferingSocketHandler

rootLogger = logging.getLogger('')
rootLogger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
socketHandler = BufferingSocketHandler('localhost',
                    logging.handlers.DEFAULT_TCP_LOGGING_PORT,
                    'logging-buffer.bin')
# don't bother with a formatter, since a socket handler sends
# the event as an unformatted pickle
rootLogger.addHandler(socketHandler)
```

This code is tested with **Python 3 only**, I don't know if it is Python-2-compatible.

Comment: Thanks for this very well written and complete answer. If you wouldn't mind also answering a few questions I have. Why do you suggest to use a database to store the log records? It seems a bit overkill for just logging a few message every couple of seconds. And, is logging to a database more thread safe than acquiring a lock before reading/writing to the file?

Comment: Yes, a database would much likely be overkill, but if your application uses a database anyway you could use it for log-record-buffering as well. I don't have much experience in writing thread-safe code, I've only heard that many strange things can happen. Depending on your OS a file system buffer could possibly be getting in your way, I don't know how Python's implementation handles opening/closing files. I suppose, my Thread-safety-issue was just a precaution for a late-evening quick-and-dirty solution. :-)

Comment: Argh okay I see. No my program doesn't currently use a database but I will keep it in mind if it ever does. I was thinking to avoid any problems with multi-threading/processing I would log all messages to the `QueueHandler` and then to the `BufferingSocketHandler` from the `QueueListener`. This also has the advantage of not blocking the main program when trying to log to a server that is down before timing out.