# Python: Save bytes to log with timestamp efficiently

Tags: python, logging, save

I have a UDP package comming in every 2 seconds that I read with socket and then extract the UDP data to a bitarray.

Each bit in the bitarray corresponds to a true/false value for a certain condition. The conditions they correspond to are static.

I want to store the data from each UDP package on the hard drive so I can later read those and go back in time to see the true/false status of each condition. I have been thinking of doing this using the logging module but it does not seem to be very efficient for storing this kind of data. I have bytes that I can store that take up hardly any space. I have essentially 60 bytes and a timestamp to store each 2 seconds for a very long period of time.

I want to be able to store this data in files of one week long.

Should I use the logging module for this or are there more efficient ways that I could not find yet. If anyone can point me to a good library that would be great!

Regards,

Berend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found a library doing this, but you could use a small `FileBuffer` class I've written for [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29594158/1525423). The data is being saved in [`pickled` state](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/pickle.html), bringing the advantage of less disk space taken, although the data is not human-readable anymore. But since your data is a binary string representing an array of boolean values, this might not be a problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import os
import pickle
import time

class BinaryFileBuffer:
    def __init__(self, basename):
        self.basename = basename

    @property
    def fname(self):
    # call other function for better inherit-and-overwrite-behaviour
        return self.get_filename()

    def get_filename(self):
        return '{}.bin'.format(self.basename)

    def write(self, data):
        with open(self.fname, 'ba') as f:
            pickle.dump(data, f)

    def write_ts(self, data):
        self.write((time.time(), data))

    @property
    def size(self):
        return int(os.path.isfile(self.fname) \
                and os.path.getsize(self.fname))

    def __iter__(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            try:
                with open(self.fname, 'br') as f:
                    while True:
                        yield pickle.load(f)
            except EOFError:
                return

    def flush(self):
        if self.size > 0:
            os.remove(self.fname)
```

This data representation results in very little overhead, when saving 60 Bytes with timestamp you'll get 82 Bytes on disk. Assuming 60 Bytes per two seconds for one week, you'll end up with a 23.6MB file for 17.3MB raw data.

To let this file "rotate", simply modify the filename to include the current year and week:

```
class RotatingBinaryFileBuffer(BinaryFileBuffer):
    def get_filename(self):
        # append year and week number to basename
        return '{}_{}.bin'.format( \
                 self.basename, time.strftime('%Yw%W'))
```

A possible test case could be as following:

```
from random import randint
def randstr(strlen):
    # include only printable characters
    return ''.join(chr(randint(32, 126)) for i in range(strlen))
buf = RotatingBinaryFileBuffer('data')
buf.write_ts(randstr(60))
for item in buf:
    print(item)
buflen = max(i for i,_ in enumerate(buf)) + 1
print("\nBytes per entry: {}".format(buf.size/buflen))
```

This is somehow a "quick'n'dirty" self-made solution, but maybe you have some kind of use for it.